# How can I add a contour plot to a scatterplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have created a scatterplot of the first principal component versus the second principal component, coloured by a categorical variable using the code below:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=dataframe['principal component 1'], y=dataframe['principal component 2'], hue=dataframe['categorical variable'])
```

I want to add a contour plot, to get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Provide ur exemplary dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This is exemplary data and implemented solution, for better result, provide your dataset (with demo data)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=3, random_state=42, cluster_std=2.0)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principal_components = pca.fit_transform(X)

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'principal component 1': principal_components[:, 0],
                           'principal component 2': principal_components[:, 1],
                           'categorical variable': y})

sns.scatterplot(x=data['principal component 1'], y=data['principal component 2'], hue=data['categorical variable'])

sns.kdeplot(x=data['principal component 1'], y=data['principal component 2'], levels=5,hue=data['categorical variable'], linewidths=0.5)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: You need one minor change to this to match the OPs request. In the call to `kdeplot` add in `hue=data['categorical variable']` and remove `color='k'`, so that the contour colours matched the scatter points.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks